# windows "modular/sandboxed" software installation

Tags: windows, installation, sandbox, virtualization

As IT guys, we all help that friend or family member in need of our services. And we all occasionally have to install some program that we are never going to use again. So you install it, do your thing and remove it afterwards. But with installing and removing a lot of software, things get left behind: registry keys, profiles, logs, sometimes even a service. Now I don't like that mess, and it slows down my computer. So once every 4-6 months I have to do a clean install (got some images to fasten it up, but still annoying)

I'm looking for a way to "freeze" my system and start tracking all changes made, so I can remove them afterwards. Ideally I can store them as a file.

For example: I'm helping a friend out whose phone died, galaxy sWhatever. I have to install the drivers, KIES (I believe it was), some tools to get root access. After it's done I remove everything again. Two weeks later, he did it again. Reinstall drivers, kies, tools ... NOT convenient.

So I'm looking for a way to capture/virtualize/save/monitor programs, and installations. Perhaps get them to run modular. (Samsung problem? load my saved Android sdk session, load my Samsung drivers&tools session)

It would be perfect if it works with bigger stuff as well, like Visual Studio. It has several services (like slq) and resources and I only use it once every other month or so.

My search has led me to things like

- VM's (which is my current solution) but it has large files, difficult to share files and devices, updates (every .. bloody .. time!).
- Sandboxing (not what i'm looking for)
- stuff like Docker. Which is somewhat what I'm looking for, but I need it on a personal level and not in a linux-VM

Any ideas? Anyone facing similar challenges? How do you deal with this?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is off topic here for several reasons. First, it's asking for product recommendations, which is specifically off topic according to the [help/on-topic]. Second, it is not programming related - this site is for specific questions related to programming and programming tools such as IDEs and compilers, not general software support. General computer questions belong on [su] instead, but questions asking for software or tool recommendations are off-topic there as well.

Comment: True! I will repost on Super User (wasn't familiar with that).
As far as product recommendations go... more interested in what kind of technology that could help me, not what product specifically.